# Is it possible to delete a firebase user in flutter without having the users credentials

Tags: firebase, flutter

I know there are alot of examples to delete the currentUser, but my app manages its own users by a single admin. The admin are required to delete users, i have deleted the user in the firestore

```
await _read(firebaseFirestoreProvider)
        .userListRef()
        .doc(userId).delete();
```

But I still need to remove the actual user which does not seem possible without having the users credentials or being the current user.

Something like this, but i don't have the creds of the user i want to delete, i also don't want to save it in firestore

```
    AuthCredential credentials =
      EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: email, password: password);
  print(user);
  AuthResult result = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials);
  await DatabaseService(uid: result.user.uid).deleteuser(); // called from database class
  await result.user.delete();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that deletes the user.

Since Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK and are executed in the back-end, you don't need to "be the current user" to delete the user. You simply use the [`deleteUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#deleteuser) method, as detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) which explains how to use the Admin SDK to manage the Firebase Authentication users.

From your Flutter app, you call the Cloud Function as explained in the FlutterFire [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage#calling-endpoints), and pass the uid of the user to be delete (or the email, since you can use the [`getUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#getuser) or [`getUserByEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#getuserbyemail) methods in the Cloud Function).

In the Cloud Function, you verify that the calling user is an admin before deleting the user. As a matter of fact with Callable Cloud Functions, the Firebase Authentication token is automatically included in requests and you can get the calling user's uid with `context.auth.uid`.